# Read stdin with line break in C

Tags: c, loops, stream, newline, line-breaks

I am very new to C and I am trying to read a `stdin` with line breaks. A text file will be used as a stream.

from what I have learned so far, I am trying this (when running the code, `< text.txt` is used to get the file:

```
int main() {
    char textInput[100];

    fgets(textInput, 100, stdin);
    printf("%s", textInput);

    return 0;
}
```

and the file text is something like:

```
hello
my
name
is
marc
```

so as a result I am only Getting the `Hello` printed out. I am pretty sure I have to used a loop for this but I tried a bunch of things but nothing is working. I am kind of confused on how to keep printing even after encountering a line break.

Comment: `while(fgets(textInput, sizeof textInput, stdin) != NULL)`

Comment: 5 lines ... so loop 5 times `for (int n = 0; n < 5; n++) { fgets(...); printf(...); }`

Comment: You'll need to redirect your text file as `stdin` when you run the program, which doesn't seem to be real code that does what you claim.

Comment: *"I tried a bunch of things but nothing is working"*, so the problem is in that code. Hard to help ig you don't show the code you're having trouble with.

Comment: @WeatherVane The code in the question seems to me to do what the OP explains. It seems to be implicit that the text file is given from stdin.

Comment: @hyde it won't compile, even with library header.

Comment: Well, the lineSize is missing, so yeah, definitely not a [mcve].

Comment: @Hyde and the string array has a different name. You very well know that "something like my code" isn't well received. It was definitely not the code that was used.

Comment: @WeatherVane This seems to be surprisingly well received so far, considering how it seems to be a "please write my code for me" type of question. Anyway, the mistakes are probably due to manual copying or something, because OP says output is "hello", which matches the code. Unless that is in the excercise deacription already, and OP didn't actually do anything...

Comment: Don't use LineSize, just do: `char textInput[100];  fgets(textInput, sizeof textInput , stdin);`. Note that this will need to change if you ever convert textInput to be a `char *`.

Comment: @WeatherVane, i am using the commad line < text.txt when i run the program. The code i first posted was not the update one, thats my mistake . just updated it... and that is actually my real code . As i said,i am very new to c so there are still a lot of concepts i am not yet understanding

Comment: @hyde Thank you for your answer. To go further, this is not a "write my code for me" this is just to gather suggestion on how to tackle this. I did write the code  and yes that was a copying mistake. i update with the right one. lineSize ws just a constant for the length of the array.

Comment: Have you tried the loop in my first comment?

Comment: @WeatherVane yes i just tried it. Thanks a lot it works. i used to try while(textInput !=EOF), but it was giving me an error so i guess EOF is not supposed to be here since we are not opening a file directly right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track: you read a single line, so you only get a single line of output. To read the whole file, you must use a loop. `fgets()` returns the destination pointer if inout was successful and it returns `NULL` at the end of file, so the loop is quite simple:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char textInput[100];

    while (fgets(textInput, sizeof textInput, stdin)) {
        printf("%s", textInput);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour la reponse. J'avais essaye quelques While loop avec EOF mais je recevais toujours des erreurs.

Comment: `fgets(textInput, sizeof textInput, stdin)` is an easier to maintain idiom.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: yes of course. Too bad there is no simple way to ensure that the `sizeof` argument is an actual array in this idiom.